# First AJAX project...(wont load text file inline)

Tags: ajax, text

This is my first time working with AJAX, and I cant seem to figure out WHY the .txt file will NOT load? but instead goes to a new page with just that text displayed)  ie: not loading in the same page:

my index.html page:

```
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Learning Ajax</title>

</head>

<body>
    <!-- my first AJAX script -->


    <h1>Learning Ajax</h1>

    <a href="files/ajax.txt">Load Text Files</a>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

here is my main.js script:

```
var message = "Test";

(function() {   

var link = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

link.onClick = function(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //handle the 'onreadystatechange" event
    //0 = un-initialized
    //1 = loading
    //2 = loaded (sent to server)
    //3 = interactive (server is responding)
    //4 = complete (request finished)

    xhr.readystatechange = function(){
        if((xhr.readyState == 4) && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 304)){
            xhr.responseText;           

            var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];            
            var p = document.createElement("p");            
            var pText = document.createTextNode(xhr.responseText);          
            p.appendChild(pText);
            body.appendChild(p);
        };       
        //open the request
        xhr.open("GET", "files/ajax.txt", true);         
        //send the request
        xhr.send(null);     
        return false;
    };  
};
})();

alert(message);
```

in my ajax.txt file.. I just have some random plain text: This is Ajax text to be loaded.

I am NOT running this locally, but through localhost using WAMP web server..

What am I missing? or overlooking here?

Tutorial link:  tutsplus.com/lesson/the-simplest-ajax-script

Comment: try changing your content to {'This is Ajax text to be loaded'} and the file name to ajax.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to solve your problem:

Make this replacement to your code:

- onClick -> onclick (js is case sensitive)
- readystatechange  -> onreadystatechange

then put this piece of code out of the onreadystatechange function:

```
//open the request
xhr.open("GET", "files/ajax.txt", true);         
//send the request
xhr.send(null);     
return false;
```

This is the new main.js:

```
var message = "Test";

(function() {
var link = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
link.onclick = function(){
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

//handle the 'onreadystatechange" event
//0 = un-initialized
//1 = loading
//2 = loaded (sent to server)
//3 = interactive (server is responding)
//4 = complete (request finished)   
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if((xhr.readyState == 4) && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 304)){

        xhr.responseText;           

        var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];            
        var p = document.createElement("p");            
        var pText = document.createTextNode(xhr.responseText);          
        p.appendChild(pText);
        body.appendChild(p);
    };       

    return false;
};  

//open the request
xhr.open("GET", "files/ajax.txt?aiai", true);         
//send the request
xhr.send(null);     
return false;
};
})();

alert(message);
```

Comment: accepted as better answer, as it focuses/use the code supplied for the answer.  (Summary: I needed to move the open()/send() routine outside of the onreadystatechange() function... (also the first return false; doesnt look to be needed)

Thats for pointing out my error!

-w

Answer (score 0):

I think its easier to do it like that:

first, HTML:

```
    <html>

    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Learning Ajax</title>

    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- my first AJAX script -->


        <h1>Learning Ajax</h1>

        <a href="#" onClick="loadText()">Load Text Files</a>
        <div id="textFiles"><!-- files display here --></div>


    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
<script>

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
    var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}




function loadText() {   
    var message = "Test";
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
        document.getElementById("textFiles").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            alert(message);
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("textFiles").innerHTML = "Loading Files...";
    }

};
xmlhttp.open("POST",'files/ajax.txt',true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.. however, because I am NEW to AJAX (first time using it)  I'd like to try and understand the example given and why it isnt working. Instead of working off an entirely new script.  Can explain why the original code doesnt work for 'me'...but does in the tutorial?